# How to evaluate factorials greater than $69!$

Tags: permutations, factorial, calculator

How to evaluate factorials greater than $69!$?
On my calculator, $69!$ is the largest number I can enter before it gives me a syntax error, most likely due to an overflow.

Is there a way to evaluate huge numbers such as $493!$ by hand? I understand if this method exists (which it probably does, I hope.) that it might be very complex, but any answer is appreciated. Thanks in advance. (To 3 decimals places.)

Comment: How accurately do you want to calculate?

Comment: To 3 decimal places x$10^n$ where $n$ is a power, really large power. @MarkBennet

Comment: [Related](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=493%21).

Comment: Use Wolfram-Alpha [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com) . It can give a very large stuff very accurately (The exact!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can quickly get a very accurate calculation $n!$ by Stirling's approximation:

$$
n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right) ^n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{12n} + \frac{1}{288 n^2} \right)
$$
For $n = 439$ this is accurate to one part in 50 billion.

Your big headache is representing that number on your calculator or in a float number of a computer.  That is why people working with factorials of large numbers frequently work with $\log (n!)$.

The answer, by the way, works out to 
$$1.279533 \cdot 10^{971} $$

Comment: Thanks so much! I know this is a pain but can you please show this using an example of a larger number, I did it using $5!$ which gave me $120.0025456$ (which is amazing) but how do I do it without my calculator? Or should I just do every part separately and put them all back together at the end? **EDIT** Just saw your edit, but how did you get that value? If you did use a calculator what method did you take?

Comment: Your calculator is limited to $10^{100}$, so anything over $69!$ overflows.  There are online calculators like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=439%21) which will overcome this. It will even give you all $972$ digits if you want.  In a calculator limited to $10^{100}$ you can calculate $\log 439!$ using Stirling's approximation.  Then the integer part is $971$ which gives you the exponent of $10$.  Taking $10$ to the power of the fractional part will give you the leading digits.

Comment: That makes more sense! Thanks @RossMillikan

Comment: @SamirChahine:  for three place accuracy you can ignore the last term.  $\frac 1{12\cdot 439}\lt \frac 1{5000}$ so the error there is quite small.

Comment: The way I did it was to take the log of (n/e) and multiplied that by n, then actually add up the expression in the parentheses and took the log of that, then took half the log of $2n\pi$, added all three logs, and that gave me the exponent; then I took the fractional part and raised 10 to that power to get the mantissa.  That would work fine for even a number like 10000!

Answer (score 1):

A more direct approach with the calculator:

$$ 493! = \frac{69!}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{119}P_{50}}{10^{100}} \times
\frac{^{165}P_{46}}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{209}P_{44}}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{251}P_{42}}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{292}P_{41}}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{332}P_{40}}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{371}P_{39}}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{409}P_{38}}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{446}P_{37}}{10^{100}} \times 
\frac{^{483}P_{37}}{10^{100}} \times 
^{493}P_{10} \times
(10^{100})^{11}
$$

You can sort of "cheat" your calculator's limitations by dividing powers of ten and manually appending $10^n$ at the end, remembering what you took away. This gives a **fully accurate** answer, with the precision of your calculator's. The speed to which you can evaluate larger factorial decreases, but it's still technically almost limitless if you're really desperate. Plus, it's still quick method for the low hundreds, an especially neat trick for the evaluation of those.

Here is a table for the largest consecutive permutations that do not exceed $10^{100}$, for quicker evaluations up to $1000!$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{i}& \text{Factorial} & \text{Difference}  \\ \hline
1& 69& 69\\ \hline
2& 119& 50\\ \hline
3& 165& 46\\ \hline
4& 209& 44\\ \hline
5& 251& 42\\ \hline
6& 292& 41\\ \hline
7& 332& 40\\ \hline
8& 371& 39\\ \hline
9& 409& 38\\ \hline
10& 446& 37\\ \hline
11& 483& 37\\ \hline
12& 520& 37\\ \hline
13& 556& 36\\ \hline
14& 592& 36\\ \hline
15& 627& 35\\ \hline
16& 662& 35\\ \hline
17& 697& 35\\ \hline
18& 732& 35\\ \hline
19& 766& 34\\ \hline
20& 800& 34\\ \hline
21& 834& 34\\ \hline
22& 868& 34\\ \hline
23& 901& 33\\ \hline
24& 934& 33\\ \hline
25& 967& 33\\ \hline
26& 1000& 33\\ \hline
\end{array}

Sorry for being four years late...